# using php and curl to update mediawiki

Tags: php, post, curl, mediawiki

I've been working on a php script to update mediawiki entries, however whenever I run it it doesn't seem to update the wiki at all and just returns the article page unedited.

I've included a section which logs into the wiki first and I've successfully read information off the wiki but I have not been able to update it.

Is there something I'm missing or better yet is there an existing php package which can be used to update a mediawiki.

thanks in advance,

sample code follows:

```
function curl_post_page($site, $post ) {
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';
$headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'; 

//var_dump($post);
$cl = curl_init($site);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT)");
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [several client libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot#PHP) available ([known good revision](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot&oldid=522287489#PHP) | [mirror at archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20110717110455/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot#PHP))

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Added wikipedia and archive.org archives of the page -- I believe wikipedia and archive.org to be better archives/mirrors of this content than my post can hope to be.  The internet archive at archive.org has been providing mirrors of this nature for over a decade.

Answer (score 0):

Is the api writing enabled? ([$wgEnableWriteAPI](http://tinyurl.com/wgEnableWriteAPI) = false;) It is disabled by default for versions below 1.14.

Are you getting any [errors](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Errors#Standard_errors) back?